# Unit Testing events in multi-threaded app

Tags: .net, multithreading, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am unit testing a component that does work on any number of threads and raises events on those threads. I have written a simple event register that I use to assert that the events I expect have been raised:

```
    public class EventRegister
    {
        private readonly object _lock = new object();
        public int Count { get; private set; }

        public void Increment()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                Count++;
                Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
            }
        }

        public static EventRegister operator ++(EventRegister counter)
        {
            counter.Count++;
            return counter;
        }

        public static implicit operator int(EventRegister counter)
        {
            return counter.Count;
        }

        public bool HasFired { get { return Count > 0; } }

        public void Wait(int unitCount)
        {
            Wait(unitCount, TimeSpan.MinValue);
        }

        public void Wait(int unitCount, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                var start = DateTime.Now;

                while (Count < unitCount)
                {
                    if (timeout != TimeSpan.MinValue && !Debugger.IsAttached)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(_lock, timeout);

                        if (DateTime.Now-start>timeout)
                            throw new TimeoutException();
                    }
                    else
                        Monitor.Wait(_lock);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this works fine and I happy enough with it, but have I reinvented the wheel? Does NUnit or MOQ (or any other lib) already include some other mechanism for doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your 2 questions:

- You have reinvented the wheel. Not quite the same wheel model I have (re) invented myself, but quite similar nonetheless. I am pretty sure a lot of other persons reinvented such a wheel somewhere else as well.
- Moq does not provide such functionality, neither does MSTest. Last time I did use NUnit, it did not provide it.

A lot of multi-thread, event-based boiler plate code seems to be written over and over again. Maybe it is time for a framework-agnostic thread and event helper library to be built...

Comment: you kick it off, I'll join you, see you on BitBucket?  https://bitbucket.org/mylesmcdonnell